# Trying to split a string (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I'm new to Ruby. I'm trying to make some simple calculator program. So, basically what it's supposed to do is you input something like
4+2
and it outputs 6. Simple, right? So I thought. I'm trying to split a string at all the operation characters, so I made this quick regex thinking it would work. It didn't.

```
class Calculator 
def add(a,b)
    return a+b
end
def sub(a,b)
    return a-b
end
def div(a,b)
    return a/b
end
def mul(a,b)
    return a*b
end
end

operation = gets.split("[\/\+\-\*]")
print(operation)
sleep()
```

the sleep() is there to pause the console so I can take a look at my outputs. But right now, it's outputting `["4+2\n"]`?? I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need some help. (it should output `["4","+","2"]`). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular expression you want to use `/` instead of `"`:

`operation = gets.split(/[\/\+\-\*]/) # ["4", "2\n"]`

There's an extra newline remove that with strip:

`operation = gets.strip.split(/[\/\+\-\*]/) # ["4", "2"]`

But we lost the operator.   Looking at the docs for [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split):

> If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned
>   in the array as well.

Adding `()` in our regex creates a group. So then we have:

`operation = gets.strip.split(/([\/\+\-\*])/) # ["4", "+", "2"]`

Comment: thanks so much, but I don't understand the gets.strip.split. I understand that it strips the newline, but shouldn't it be `gets.split(whatever).strip`?

Comment: Split returns an array.  strip operates on the string, I'm removing the newling before calling split.

Comment: -1 learn what to escape in regex before posting regex answers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape every character inside of your character class. Consider the following:

```
operation = gets.gsub(/[^\d\/*+-]/, '').split(/([\/*+-])/)
```

or

```
operation = gets.split(/([\/*+-])/).map(&:strip)
```

Comment: Yes, but use `\d` instead of `0-9`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
operation = gets.chomp.gsub(/[\/\+\-\*]/, ';\0;').split(";")
print(operation)
```

Execution result:

```
4+2/3*9-0
["4", "+", "2", "/", "3", "*", "9", "-", "0"]
```